# Accessing table from a sub-query inside an inner join - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an SQL query as follows -

```
select 
* 
from A
inner join AA on A.id = AA.aid
inner join AAA on 
(
  select B.bid, B.bname 
  from B
  inner join C on B.id = C.bid
  where C.aaid = AA.id
) as B1 on A.id = B1.aid
```

Which gives an error

> Unknown column 'AA.id' in 'where clause'

It will be very helpful if someone can tell me the reason and provide me with a possible solution.

Comment: SQL Server isn't MySQL. Please don't tag irrelevant RDBMS.

Comment: On note for your question, isn't the column `AA.aid`?

Comment: Yes it is @Larnu. This should be disclosed as a typo error/mistake honestly.

Comment: No, its AA.id. in the where clause inside the inner join

Comment: Obviously, the subquery joins just B and C, it doesn't know about the table AA, so you can't use it in the where condition

Comment: I'm not a user of MySQL, however, if this is SQL Server then you can't reference tables outside of a sub select in a `JOIN`. You have to either use `CROSS APPLY` or include the criteria in your `ON`. I would guess the same applies MySQL.

Comment: Is there any way that I can use to access the previous inner joined table AA inside the second inner join's subquery?

Comment: Sub queries act as their own... You subquery runs on its own forms two columns [a table] which you join with the other two tables

Comment: @Raj one way, that is `join` AA in subquery.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you need something like this

```
select 
* 
from A
inner join AA on A.id = AA.aid
inner join AAA on AA.id = AAA.aid 
inner join
(
  select B.bid, B.bname, C.aaid
  from B
  inner join C on B.id = C.bid
) as B1 on A.id = B1.aid and AA.id = B1.aaid
```

It is not possible to reference outer aliases in join subqueries in MySQL. In PostgreSQL you could use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` and in SQL Server `CROSS APPLY`, however, there is no such thing in MySQL.

Comment: Thumbs up @Radim. 
However, I have already tried this. But this won't help, as I will be needing an "order by" and "limit 1" after the "where" clause inside the inner join's sub-query

Comment: @Raj And why is that a problem?  What error do you get?  And please clarify if you're using SQL Server or MySQL.  *(Using MySQL syntax such as `LIMIT 1` in SQL Server is always going to give errors, because SQL Server uses `SELECT TOP(1) x FROM y ORDER BY z`...)*

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding,

```
select 
* 
from #a1 a1 --A
inner join #a2 a2 on a1.i = A2.i --AA
inner join #a3 a3 on a1.i = a3.i --AAA
inner join
(
  select B.i, a2.i ai
  from #b b --B
  inner join #c c on B.i = C.i --C
  inner join #a2 a2 on a2.i = C.i  --AA
) as B1 
on A1.i = B1.i
and B1.ai = a2.i
```

Lack of sample data, we help as assumption.

Revert me, if query needs updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, so ...

Let's say you didn't write the subquery in the `FROM` clause as an ad-hoc view, but make it an explicit view `B1` (with `CREATE VIEW`). Then your query would read

```
select * 
from A
inner join AA on A.id = AA.aid
inner join AAA on B1 on A.id = B1.aid
```

which illustrates that your syntax is off.

Moreover the `B1` select doesn't contain an `aid`, only a `bid` and a `bname`.

At last the `ON` clause for `AAA` doesn't contain any reference to the table `AAA`, so this is not really a join criteria for that table.

This is the answer to what's wrong with your query. I cannot show you the correct query, though, because it's completely unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please elaborate. It's probably quite simple and you're over-complicating things :-)